# The best way for connecting multiple JavaScript applications/classes

Tags: javascript

I need to connect multiple JavaScript applications/class in a JavaScript framework . 
In general, an application may need to notify another that an event has occurred, but does not need to wait for a response.

I would like to know if there are alternatives to `"Message queue"` and `"observer pattern"`. 
For example, which solution has been implemented in utility like Google+, Facebook, LinkedIn or other JavaScript frameworks?

My case is an e-learning platform with over 10000 of users,
the framework includes over 20 classes and a lot of listeners working in parallel.

This application consists of a single global object and all the other javascript classes are loaded and unloaded dynamically.

So, since all the classes/apps are visible from the global object I was thinking that a good option could be the following:

for each app:

```
MyApp.prototype.open = function () {
    this.events = { "myEvent": this.onMyEvent }
    ...
};

MyApp.prototype.onMyEvent = function (data) {
   // do something
};
```

Then the global object will be responsible to execute the function at apps level.

Your comments and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds that events (the observer pattern) would be pretty reasonable in your situation. Is there any problem with events that makes you look for alternatives? I don't know about events in Google+ and Facebook, but they're used naturally in the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html), for instance.

A light-weight events library is [eve](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/eve) ([reference here](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/eve/)), which is used in the increasingly popular [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) graphics library.